# Тебе (—) нет, а им (—) да

Tags: пунктуация

Такой у меня был диалог в переписке:

— ...К тому же ты об этом не промолчал.
— Тебе нет, а им — да.

Не придирайтесь, пожалуйста, к тому, что, возможно, не очень хорошо сказать "промолчать кому-то". "Промолчал" в данном случае "не сказал".

Меня интересует, правильно ли, что после "тебе" нет тире, а после "им" есть. В общем, я хочу узнать правильный вариант и понять, почему именно так правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, насколько правильно, но мне такой выбор пунктуации понятен. После "им" явно пропущено слово (глагол?), тире эллиптическое.

А перед "нет" такое тире опционально, поскольку "нет" - это историческое "не есть", сохранившие рудиментарные семантические признаки глагола. Таким образом, перед "нет" можно и не углядеть пропущенного слова - по желанию.

Comment: Спасибо, behemothus! Я рад, что интуиция мне правильно подсказала. :)

Answer (score 4):

Это неполные предложения с разговорной грамматикой, знаки препинания ставятся в соответствии с интонацией:

— Тебе нЕт, а Им — дА.

В первой части логическое ударение перенесено на слово "нет", пауза отсутствует, тире тоже. Во втором случае на оба слова падает ударение, тире обозначает паузу.

Семантика сообщения: Тебе нЕт (=не промолчАл), а Им - дА (=промолчАл).

Comment: *В первой части логическое ударение перенесено на слово "нет",* - из чего это следует? Мне кажется, что ударение как раз здесь на  "тебе". А "нет" - идет от контекста.Впрочем, и во второй части все весьма условно.

Comment: Спасибо, Sibylla! А я именно так и воспринимаю, что на "нет" падает ударение. Видимо, поэтому так интуитивно и расставил тире, как раз в соответствии с логикой Sibyll-ы (обращаюсь к вам обоим).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, "к нам обоим" под ответом Sibyll'ы можно обращаться, только указав мой ник в начале сообщения, после знака "@". Иначе - дело случая, что я вообще увижу ваше сообщение. По сути. Артем, желая угодить всем, вы добились обратного. Логика Sibyll'ы  мне не ясна и комментировать её не буду. На мой взгляд, если вы точно уверены, что на "нет" падает ударение - и нет других мотивирующих факторов - то тире перед "нет" не только возможно, но и очень даже желательно. Только не эллиптическое, а интонационное.  Ибо вы неизбежно делаете там интонационную ("мхатовскую") паузу.

Comment: Если я и делаю после "тебе" паузу, то только оооочень маленькую, гораздо меньше, чем после "им". Не привык я эти "@" писать...